# Scala match and reference equality check

Tags: scala

Depending on the variable type Scala sometimes match value and sometimes don't.
The problem is illustrated by this simple program:

```
class NotEqualToAnything {
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = false
}

val x = new NotEqualToAnything()
x match {
  case `x` =>
    println("WTF x equal to itself")
  case _ =>
    println("no-match") // This got printed
}

val y: AnyRef = new NotEqualToAnything()
y match {
  case `y` =>
    println("WTF y equal to itself") // This got printed
  case _ =>
    println("no-match")
```

When the variable is of type `AnyRef` the generated code contains a call to `BoxesRunTime.equals` which does indeed a `y == y` check before calling `y.equals(y)`. When the type of the variable is `NotEqualToAnything`, we got a standard `x == null` check twice and then a call to `x.equals(x)`.

I tested this on

```
Scala 2.13.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_201).
```

I wonder if this is a compiler bug and should be reported of if this is a "desired" behavior. In my opinion both cases should behave identically.

One hypothesis is that compiler expects classes to follow the contract when overriding `equals`, and so expects `equals` to be reflective (`x.equals(x) == true`). Can somebody confirm that this is indeed the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [a contract for `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). `x.equals(x)` has to be true. If you break that contract, a lot of things that depend on it will not work anymore.

A compiler (and for example a collection library) has to assume the objects are "well-behaved". It is not a compiler bug if something breaks if they don't.

The upshot of this is that the compiler can optimize some things when it feels like it. In the present case, the `BoxesRunTime.equals` overhead can be skipped when the static type is known to not need that.